# No implicit arguments of type: Zero[DenseVector[Double]]

Tags: scala, breeze, implicit

Since I have upgraded Breeze library from version 1.0 to version 2.1.0 I cannot create a `DenseMatrix[DenseVector[Double]]` I got the following error:

No implicit arguments of type: Zero[DenseVector[Double]]

Here is an example of a code

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix, DenseVector}
import breeze.math.Ring.ringFromField

object Example {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val list = Array(DenseVector(0.12), DenseVector(0.0), DenseVector(0.0),DenseVector(0.12))
    val mat = DenseMatrix(list).reshape(2,2)
}
}
```

The code works fine with breeze 1.0! Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Does it solve your issue?

Comment: I did something similar and it worked! Thank you

Comment: Great. Then closing as a duplicate.